# response headers for google cloud storage

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Using Google Cloud Storage, I do not get CORS header in response for one file, but all other files contain it.

I uploaded a folder of SVG files to be served from Google Cloud Storage. I put them in a new bucket. I changed the permissions so that all files would be served to the public. I used the `gsutil` tool to [set the CORS headers with a JSON file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket) for the bucket. I confirmed the CORS setting succeeded with `gsutil cors get gs://bucket`.

The response for each object/file correctly contains the desired CORS header, EXCEPT FOR ONE of the files I uploaded!

This file happens to be alphabetically first, not sure if that is helpful. I tried deleting the file with the problem, re-uploading, and re-applying the CORS setting with gsutil. No luck! Requests for the same file are still missing the desired CORS header.

- How can I fix the response for the single file lacking CORS header?
- Why is this happening?

**UPDATE:**
**The behavior changed. The CORS header is now present. It was wrong for a long time (60 minutes?), but fixed now. Why??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your update, it sounds like your object was cached. See the note about [Cache Control and Consistency](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency#eventually_consistent_operations) in the documentation.

Comment: Agreed! That goes along with the header configuration I used, `"maxAgeSeconds": 3600`.